# Is a donation page viable for free applications?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, donations

I want to add a donation page for my free iPhone app. But I can't see anyway to implement this properly. Does apple allow inapp purchases to act as donations? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Samar

Answer (score 0):

Do check the App Store guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

You can only add donations to free apps if the donations go towards "recognized charitable organizations" (§21.1), and the collection of donations are done via a web site in Safari or via an SMS (§21.2). Donations cannot be added to apps that cost.

If the donations are to your own personal welfare, that is not allowed, you can earn money either by charging for the application, using IAP for approved reasons, or from advertisement services.